# Using gulp and typescript with gulp-tsc gulp-typings

Tags: node.js, express, gulp, tsc, typescript-typings

I am trying to make a simple nodejs express API with typescript, tsc and gulp. When I compile my .ts files with tsc no errors occur. Now I am trying to integrate gulp into my workflow using gulp-tsc and gulp-typings in gulpfile.js [Github Project with gulpfile.js](https://github.com/JMStudiosJoe/NodejsPractice/blob/GulpJSIntegrationBranch/nodejs_express_typescript/gulpfile.js)
I am not seeing where to connect the two since I am still getting errors from gulp about not finding express or body-parser [image]

I have tried to merge them with merge-stream but still the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you have express and body-parser packages installed?

Comment: What I did not have was those packages installed for the .js files but only for the .ts files that is why the tsc compiled but the node doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Needed to install the necessary packages for the .js files to know express and body-parser were installed, that is why tsc compiled but node didn't. I assumed installing for typings was also installing for the .js files as well, but that was not the case.